# Differentiable normalize K-max function

Tags: probability, derivatives, normal-distribution

Is there any differentiable function exists that for a given vector a `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and parameter `k=4` produce a vector like this:

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.8, 0.9 ,1.09 ,1.19]
sum(output)= 4
```

The maximum value of each entries is 4 and the minimum is 0. The values can be anything between 0 to 4.

The things that I need is very similar to [k-winner-take-all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winner-take-all_(computing)) with following constraint:

```
sum(output) = k
```

Any pointer/reference for such mathematic functions is appreciated.

Comment: There is many! For example all $0$ but one of them that be $4$. So you must set some other restriction.

Comment: @AliAshja' Thanks for your reply. For a given k=4, the four largest entries are much bigger than the rest of the entries. That is the main constraint in my case.

Comment: You should clear how the output entries are biased in terms of inputs ones.